Maclaurin Expansion of $f(x)=\frac{1+x+x^2}{1-x+x^2}$
I'm having a hard time trying to expand the following polynomial up to $x^4$ using Taylor expansion:
$$f(x)=\frac{1+x+x^2}{1-x+x^2}$$
I've got to $$f(x)=1-\frac{2}{1+x+\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{4}{(1+x+\frac{1}{x})^2}+\ldots$$
I tried many times but always end up with a negative degree polynomial.
Please help me with this.

What have you tried?

$f(x)=1+\frac2{1+x+\frac1{x}}$

I just edited what I've done.

Welcome to MSE. Please clarify the title of your post to make us know the point of it. Also, adding some additional contexts such as your trial or the source of it can be helpful to make the quality of your post higher.

Related to Siong Thye Goh's answer above, you can write:
$\displaystyle \frac{1+x+x^2}{1-x+x^2}\\ = \displaystyle \frac{\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}}{\frac{1+x^3}{1+x}}\\= \frac{1-x^3}{1+x^3}\cdot \frac{1+x}{1-x} \\= (1 - 2(\frac 1{1+x^3}))\cdot (1 - 2(\frac 1{1-x}))$.
Using standard series expansions, it's easy to get each factor to $x^4$ and multiply and sum to get the relevant terms you need.

$\frac {1 + x+ x^2}{1-x+x^2}$
$\frac {1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$
$\frac {1}{1-x+x^2} = 1 + (x-x^2) + (x-x^2)^2 + (x-x^2)^3 + \cdots $
$\frac {1 + x+ x^2}{1-x+x^2} = (1+x+x^2)(1 + (x-x^2) + (x-x^2)^2 + (x-x^2)^3 + \cdots) $
Now we need to expand out the RHS, dropping any terms of higher degree than $x^4$
$(1+x+x^2)(1 + x-x^2 + x^2 - 3x^3 + x^4 + x^3 - 3x^4 + x^4)$
$(1+x+x^2)(1 + x - 2x^3 - x^4)$
$1 + x - 2x^3 - x^4 + x + x^2 - 2x^4 + x^4 $
$1 + 2x + x^4 - x^3 - 2x^4$
Alternatively, you can start taking derivatives, and evaluate at 0.
$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0) x + \frac {f''(0)}{x^2} + \cdots$

$$1-x+x^2=\frac{1+x^3}{1+x}$$
Thus,
\begin{align}f(x) &= \frac{1+x+x^2}{1-x+x^2}\\&=\frac{(1+x+x^2)(1+x)}{1+x^3} \\&=(1+x+x^2)(1+x))(1+x^3)^{-1}\end{align}
I will leave the rest to you.
